# Firebase database setup and data handling in Swift 3

Tags: swift, dictionary, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm pretty new to swift and Firebase. I have database like this:[image: My database preview]

In the app I have multiple annotations and I need to pass the info from the database to them. At this point I got little bit confused with reading the data as dictionary and passing it to the annotations. 
This was my previous code when I didn't use database and used Arrays:

```
for i in 0...2
    {
        let coordinate = coordinates[i]
        let point = myAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: coordinate[0] , longitude: coordinate[1] ))
        point.name = names[i]
        point.address = addresses[i]
        point.hours = hours[i]
        point.phones = phones[i]

        self.mapView.addAnnotation(point)
    }
```

You don't have to code it for me but I need at least some hint please.

Comment: Show your firebase base code that you are trying.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a similar Database on my firebase, And I would do it like this:

```
FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("Data").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in
    if let snapshot = snapshot.children.allObjects as? [FIRDataSnapshot] {
        for snap in snapshot{
            if let dict = snap.value as? [String: Any] {
                if let address = dict["address"] as? String,let lat = dict["lat"] as? String, let long = dict["long"] as? String, let name = dict["name"] as? String {
                    let coordinate = coordinates[i]
                    let point = myAnnotation(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: lat , longitude: long ))
                    point.name = name
                    point.address = address

                    self.mapView.addAnnotation(point)
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```

where I loop for each child of your Data node, pass that snap value as a dictionary, and then read the dictionary and type cast its values to see if format is correct to then assign it and append it to the array.

Comment: YES, this is exactly what I was trying to do, you saved my day. Also there are 2 small inaccuracies 1, the Lat and Long has to be "as Double", 2, just delete the line "let coordinate = coordinates[i], thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Glad to help :D Yeah Im was using just string, thats why I didn't realize you where using doubles.